# Does anyone know of a tutorial series that walks you through adding clothing to a rigged character?

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting

Basically I have a modular item system that acts similar to the [BOTW](https://www.gamingboulevard.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/BreathOfTheWildWeaponsUI.png) system, with swappable items for pants, torso, and head. I've spent a crap ton of time weight painting and doing every trick I could find but my pants and shirts still deform weirdly whenever I move my character. Sometimes they even split off from the character model, and I can't fix it without making the whole model look stretched and ugly.

I've looked everywhere but most of the clothing tutorials are only about cloth physics, or skintight clothes that don't really apply to what I'm trying todo. I feel like I just must be doing it all wrong, and would appreciate something to base my work off of. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a tutorial request, which is [off topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic) for this site.

Comment: Sucks to be me. I was hoping for an answer. Guess the search continues.